# What is the most efficient method to fix different parts of a sound file (speaking)?

Tags: voice, file-organization, speech

I recorded a short testimonial. The person asking needs a little bit of pitch adjustment and to be made louder. The person replying needs to be a little louder.

In Adobe Audition as best I can tell I have a few choices:

1. Do it all in the full recording using markers
2. Create smaller new audio parts of the different segments to combine in Premier
3. Create smaller new audio parts of the different segments to combine in Multitrack

What's the most efficient way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use automation and make the adjustments on the main track.  Manually syncing audio is a pain and error-prone.  If both are speaking on the same track, you may want to make two copies of the one track changes for one person to each and then cross-fade between them to make your output.

Comment: Thats what I was thinking but unsure of the cross-fade part. I haven't really started with multitrack in Audition. Should I do the crossfade using Level keyframes in Premier?

Comment: I'd probably do it in Audition and mix it down to a track for Premiere.  It's been a while since I used Audition, but there should be a way to let you record keyframes automatically based on real time playback.  I suppose doing it in premiere is another option that might be efficient though.